# How to deploy a custom docker image on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Looking at this [blog - 5. Create Dockerfile](http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/docker/10-steps-deploying-docker-containers-on-elastic-beanstalk). It seems I had to create a new Dockerfile pointing to my private image on Docker.io.

And since the last command shall be starting an executable or the docker image would end up in nirvana, there is the supervisrd at the end:

```
FROM flux7/wp-site # This is the location of our docker container.
RUN apt-get install supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

This is a bit confusing to me, because I have a fully tested custom Docker image that ends with `supervisord`, see below:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install supervisor python build-essential python-dev python-pip python-setuptools -y
RUN apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-common postgresql-client -y
RUN apt-get install openssl openssl-blacklist openssl-blacklist-extra -y
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
RUN pip install "pip>=7.0"
RUN pip install virtualenv uwsgi

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
ADD canonicaliser_api /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
ADD config_local.py /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/config/config_local.py
RUN virtualenv /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv
RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt
RUN export CFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/
RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && cd /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/ && python setup.py build_ext --inplace
RUN cp /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/*.so /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions
RUN rm -rf /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/canonicaliser
RUN rm -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/build

RUN mkdir /var/run/flask-uwsgi
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/run/flask-uwsgi
RUN mkdir /var/log/flask-uwsgi
ADD flask-uwsgi.ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

So how do I serve my custom image (CMD ?) instead of using supervisord?  Unless I'm overlooking something....

**UPDATE**

I have applied the suggested updates, but it fails to authenticate to private repo on DockerHub.

```
[2015-08-11T14:02:10.489Z] INFO  [1858]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: WARNING: Invalid auth configuration file
  Pulling repository houmie/canon
  time="2015-08-11T14:02:08Z" level="fatal" msg="Error: image houmie/canon:latest not found"
  Failed to pull Docker image houmie/canon:latest, retrying...
  WARNING: Invalid auth configuration file
```

The `dockercfg` inside a folder called `docker` inside the S3 bucket is

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "xxxx",
                        "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
                }
        }
}
```

The `Dockerrun.aws.json` is:

```
{
   "AWSEBDockerrunVersion":"1",
   "Authentication":{
      "Bucket":"dd-xxx-ir-01",
      "Key":"docker/dockercfg"
   },
   "Image":{
      "Name":"houmie/canon",
      "Update":"true"
   },
   "Ports":[
      {
         "ContainerPort":"8888"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When deploying containers with Elastic Beanstalk, you can tell it to build your image locally on each host from a *Dockerfile* defined by you, or to use a pre-built image from a registry.

You don't necessarily have to recreate your image, you may just use one you already have (be it on Docker Hub or a private registry).

> If your application runs on an image that is available in a hosted repository, you can specify the image in a *Dockerrun.aws.json* file and omit the *Dockerfile*.

If your registry account demands authentication, then you need to provide a *.dockercfg* file on a S3 bucket, which will be pulled by Docker hosts (so you need the proper permissions given to instances via IAM Role).

> Declare the *.dockercfg* file in the Authentication parameter of the *Dockerrun.aws.json* file. Make sure that the *Authentication* parameter contains a valid Amazon S3 bucket and key. The Amazon S3 bucket must be hosted in the same region as the environment that is using it. Elastic Beanstalk will not download files from Amazon S3 buckets hosted in other regions. Grant permissions for the action *s3:GetObject* to the IAM role in the instance profile.

So, your *Dockerrun.aws.json* may look like this (considering your image is hosted on Docker Hub).

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "myBucket",
    "Key": ".dockercfg"
  },
  "Image":
  {
   "Name": "yourRegistryUser/yourImage",
   "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
     "ContainerPort": "1234"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
     "HostDirectory": "/var/app/mydb",
     "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
{
```

Look at the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) for further details about the configuration and available options.

As for what command you run (*supervisord*, whatever), it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The rules of SO dictates that the accepted answer should be self contained without the need to refer to another source to understand it.  I still don't understand it without reading the linked documentation.  Once I read it I come back again. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I realized my answer wasn't completely right as well, so I redid it with more information and specific details. Now, I think it's ok. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks for update.  I have updated my question with some updates.  Have you come across the auth problem?

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html), you don't need that "auths" object on you _dockercfg_ file.